# Export HTML table to xlsx

Tags: javascript, excel, export-to-excel

I have a table in my HTML. On click of a button I want to export the table into a xlsx file which should be downloaded.

The visible table has 2 table one for the headers and other for the data. I am trying to get a JavaScript code that works for all browsers majorly IE(v7-v11), chrome and Firefox.

Comment: What about sending it back to the server (as html) and building a server part that converts it to xlsx?
you can use html-to-xlsx
https://github.com/pofider/html-to-xlsx

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/kpegu/ Code is in jquery, removing jquery wont be a big task though...

Comment: @AmirOfir The data in my table can be huge. So i would prefer to do it on the client side if possible.

Comment: @Vishwanath The example shows the conversion to csv. How can we convert it to xlsx?

Comment: @Ace if you want to open it in spreadsheet program like Microsoft excel, CSV will work. Do you really need xlsx?

Comment: @Vishwanath Yes, I really need xlsx.

Comment: I dont think javascript can do it then, you need to send your data to server and then convert it to xlsx.

Comment: @Vishwanath There are ways to convert it to xls. Also there are third party JavaScript for xlsx. So I thought we could do it at the client side itself.

Comment: whether on client or server side, what you will ultimately need to do is create a zip archive that contains XML files in a specific folder structure that conforms to the spec, which you can find a description of at http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML-xlsx.php and a definition of at http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm. Alternatively, instead of working from the spec, you may find it easier to create some sample XLSX files that contain everything you want to support, and use their XML contents as templates.